# SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow Error: Could not deserialize object. The type could not be resolved

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, designer, workflow-activity

In development environment I have SharePoint Workflow created in SharePoint Designer. This workflow using custom activity created in Visual Studio.
After deployment web (Import-SPWeb Export-SPWeb) in production i've got error when tring to open my worklow within Designer.

```
Could not deserialize object. The type 'MyTypeHere' could not be resolved.
```

I've trying to reinstall solution and clear SharePoint Designer cache in application data. In workflow's xoml i specify right full namespace of my assembly with custom activity and this assembly exist in GAC.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I could not figure out how, but works fine now. 100% server was not restarted. May be it is because farm configuration and web.configs. Use feature activation to be sure that you control .config files.